# MySQL Calculating Timestamps

Tags: mysql, datetime, pdo

I am trying to write a query that will get the current time and subtract from it a timestamp and then see if the remainder is more then the value in a field.

I have the following query code:

```
SELECT *
FROM sessions
WHERE
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, last_used, NOW())>expiry_time
```

However although the difference between the current time-last_used is more then the expiry time, my query still returns 0 rows.

Some sample data:

```
last_used: 1388119302
expiry_time: 300
```

Comment: Add sample rows from your table to support your argument.

Comment: Alright added a sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

> Returns `datetime_expr2 – datetime_expr1`, where ***`datetime_expr1`*** and ***`datetime_expr2`*** are date or datetime expressions.

Your `last_used` value of `1388119302` is neither a date nor datetime expression.  It appears to be a UNIX time, in which case one could instead do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   sessions
WHERE  last_used + expiry_time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

However, this query cannot benefit from indexes.  You would fare better by storing the result of the addition in an indexed column of its own and using that in the above query.  You might also consider using [MySQL's native temporal data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-types.html) instead of UNIX times, so that its date functions/manipulations will work as intended.

Comment: +1 I think it should be `last_used < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-expiry_time`  to use index on `last_used`?

Comment: @valex: That would still require a full table scan in order to calculate the right operand `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-expiry_time`.

Comment: You are right. Have thought `expiry_time` is a query parameter not a field value.

Comment: I tried using the UNIX timestamp way mentioned here but it still returns 0 rows even when its well past 300 seconds.

Comment: nvm was something else. Thx for that :)